# HASHICORP VAULT: How to read multiple items from a file and write them to Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am able to write values to Vault from a json file :

```
# cat secrets.json 
{ "value": "bGktzwatc" }
{ "value": "AGktzwatB" }
```

While trying to create a new value by reading from json file, Vault is reading only the first value from the file :

```
# ./vault write secret/passwd1 @secrets.json
Success! Data written to: secret/passwd1
# ./vault read secret/passwd1
Key                 Value
---                 -----
refresh_interval    768h0m0s
value               bGktzwatc
```

Is it possible to read multiple values from a file and write to different keys through vault?

My Requirement is adding values to the multiple keys by reading from a file:

```
Key                 Value
---                 -----
refresh_interval    768h0m0s
value               bGktzwatc

Key                 Value
---                 -----
refresh_interval    768h0m0s
value               AGktzwatB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot so this, as `vault write` command expects `key` to be specified as part of the command.

When trying `> vault write @data.json` it looks like it doesn't matter what the file contains at all, as instead of `wrong file format` kind of error there is the general output about available parameters for command.

---

Maybe it will be helpful: you can specify more than one value for specific key:

```
# cat secrets.json 
{ "value1": "bGktzwatc", "value2": "AGktzwatB" }
```

then key will contains

```
Key                 Value
---                 -----
refresh_interval    768h0m0s
value1              bGktzwatc
value2              AGktzwatB
```

Comment: on vault version 1.2.3 with kv version1 ,  I get a "failed to parse k=v data; invalid key=value pair"

Answer (score 5):

If you are copying data from one key to another key via a file, this approach works for me:

```
vault read -format=json secret/mykey1 > file.json
cat file.json | jq '.data' | vault write secret/mykey2 -
```

Note the use of `jq` to bring the `"data"` sub-element to the top level first.

Answer (score 1):

Using vault 1.1.3 and the secret engine, I am able to write the secrets from a file:

```
cat secrets.json | vault write secret/yoursecrets -
```

This also works:

```
vault write secret/yoursecrets @secrets.json
```

Note that if `secrets.json` was generated using `vault read`, your secrets are in the `data` field of the JSON response, e.g. `{ "data": {"username":"Mario", "password": "It's-a me, Mario!"} }`.